# How to write a self decrypting binary file?

Tags: c, encryption, elf, memory-segmentation

I was writing a binary file which is accessing some security credentials like RSA-private key, which no one should see. I have no idea about how to keep the private key safely. Right now I am saving those information within the binary, inside `.data` section. So For security I was thinking of encrypting the data section of binary and that section will be decrypted at runtime by some small procedure within the binary. I wrote a small program which reads the binary file and encrypts the data section, and its working too. Now what I want is to decrypt the data section at runtime. But At runtime, all these sections will be loaded into memory as segments, I have very less knowledge about the getting the segment address at runtime.

So can anyone please tell me any methods that I can use to get the data section loaded into memory and to decrypt the section at runtime and to use the values stored inside data section.

Comment: Don't encrypt the entire section, there's no point.  Just encrypt the data you want.  Better yet, put the data in a separate file and encrypt that.

Comment: you don't have to use the whole section. why not just using a global variable and get it's address at run time?

Comment: but in both the above cases, if someone disassembles my binary they will be able to get the keys

Comment: what's the difference if you store the encrypted data into a global variable (just a region of memory)?

Comment: @tristan, he cant decrypt the private key. He need original key for his operations.. so that data will be useless for him

Comment: @jithin: If someone disassembles your binary, and your binary can decrypt itself, they'll get the keys (and the data) regardless. Or they can run your code under a debugger, wait for it to decrypt itself and dump its memory.

Comment: @Hasturkun , you are correct; now i have to solve one more problem :). So what will be an effective solution for this problem.

Comment: You can probably make the whole thing be somewhat painful by using a binary encrypter similar to burneye, that uses many anti-debugger tricks (Though, don't use burneye itself, since an unpacker exists). You could also force dependence on a hardware dongle (e.g HASP) that allows you to store secure data on the device. You'll probably still  be vulnerable to an attacker having the device though.

Comment: You can encrypt key with password and ask for a password upon decryption. There is no safe way of doing this without password or special hardware.